# Grouping and filtering consecutively over a dataframe

Tags: r

I am working with a large dataframe in `R` but I got the next action and my solution looks too extent. I will use `DF` as an example of the dataframe I am using:

```
library(dplyr)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c(1:10),Cause1=c(rep("Yes 1",8),rep("No 1",2)),Cause2=c(rep("Yes 2",6),rep("No 2",4)),
               Cause3=c(rep("Yes S",5),rep("No S",5)),Cause4=c(rep("Yes P",3),rep("No P",7)),
               Cause5=c(rep("Yes",2),rep("No",8)),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

`DF` has the next structure:

```
   ID Cause1 Cause2 Cause3 Cause4 Cause5
1   1  Yes 1  Yes 2  Yes S  Yes P    Yes
2   2  Yes 1  Yes 2  Yes S  Yes P    Yes
3   3  Yes 1  Yes 2  Yes S  Yes P     No
4   4  Yes 1  Yes 2  Yes S   No P     No
5   5  Yes 1  Yes 2  Yes S   No P     No
6   6  Yes 1  Yes 2   No S   No P     No
7   7  Yes 1   No 2   No S   No P     No
8   8  Yes 1   No 2   No S   No P     No
9   9   No 1   No 2   No S   No P     No
10 10   No 1   No 2   No S   No P     No
```

Where `DF` is composed of six variables (1 id variable and the others are variables that can be Yes or No). Then, for each of the variables with the prefix `Cause` I need to compute a summary of that variable, as first step, and after that I have to filter by that variable when it was achieved (or this is equal to `Yes`). For example I will do the first stage of this process with the next code and its respective explanation:

```
#Filtering stage
#N1
DF %>% group_by(Cause1) %>% summarise(N=n()) -> d1
DF %>% filter(Cause1=="Yes 1") -> DF2
```

In this case, using `dplyr` I group `DF` by variable `Cause1` and `summarise()` to count the number of values it has (`n()`). Therefore, the result is saved in `d1`. After, I have to filter `DF` when `Cause1` is equal to `Yes 1` and that must be saved in a new data.frame called `DF2`. Once I get `DF2` I must repeat a similar routine for `Cause2, Cause3, Cause4` and `Cause5`. For that I use the next code:

```
#N2
DF2 %>% group_by(Cause2) %>% summarise(N=n()) -> d2
DF2 %>% filter(Cause2=="Yes 2") -> DF3
#N3
DF3 %>% group_by(Cause3) %>% summarise(N=n()) -> d3
DF3 %>% filter(Cause3=="Yes S") -> DF4
#N4
DF4 %>% group_by(Cause4) %>% summarise(N=n()) -> d4
DF4 %>% filter(Cause4=="Yes P") -> DF5
#N5
DF5 %>% group_by(Cause5) %>% summarise(N=n()) -> d5
DF5 %>% filter(Cause5=="Yes") -> DF6
```

The final result is `DF6` but I have to make a control by combining all the dataframes `d1,d2,d3,d4` and `d5` and filtering all the `No` values. I used this code with that porpouse. The code sets a common names for all `d's` dataframes, `rbind` them and filter the `No` pattern.

```
#Connect
names(d1)<-names(d2)<-names(d3)<-names(d4)<-names(d5)<-c("Cause","N")
#Rbind
d<-rbind(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)
d_reduced<-d[grepl("No",d$Cause),]
```

I obtain this:

```
  Cause N
1  No 1 2
2  No 2 2
3  No S 1
4  No P 2
5    No 1
```

The final step is to compute the sum of `N` in `d_reduced` and the number of rows in `DF` minus that value must be the same that the number of rows of `DF6`:

```
(dim(DF)[1]-sum(d_reduced$N))==dim(DF6)[1]
```

That in this case is `TRUE`.

I would like to reduce this too long code because in my analysis the number of `Cause` variables can increase and the the code will be larger. Maybe by using the `apply` strategy or reshaping the data could be better. Any help about reducing the level of code would be marvelous. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't essentially this what you need? `DF[rowSums(sapply(DF, function(i)grepl('Yes', i))) == ncol(DF)-1,]`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

First we summarise how many "No" cases are in each column that starts with "Cause":

```
num_no <- DF %>% summarise_each(funs(substr(., 1, 1) == "N"), starts_with("Cause"))

> num_no
  Cause1 Cause2 Cause3 Cause4 Cause5
1      2      4      5      7      8
```

You are interested in the incremental difference between each subsequent column, so lets just subtract a lagged version of `num_no` from `num_no`.

```
d_reduced <- num_no - lag(num_no, 1, 0)

> d_reduced
  Cause1 Cause2 Cause3 Cause4 Cause5
1      2      2      1      2      1
```

This gives the values you wanted, but they are not the labelled, lets fix that, extracting the unique string that begins with N for each column:

```
labs <- lapply(DF, function(X){unique(X[grep("N", X)])}) %>% unlist
names(d_reduced) <- labs
> d_reduced
  No 1 No 2 No S No P No
1    2    2    1    2  1
```

Then we do your final step would be, summing the occurrences of `d_reduced` and subtracting those from number of rows of `DF` and then checking if that is equal to the number of rows which are "Yes" for their entire row.

```
> (nrow(DF) - sum(d_reduced)) == sum(DF[, ncol(DF)] == "Yes")
[1] TRUE
```

**Warning:** This would only work because if someone has yes in the final column all preceding columns are yes (like in your example). If that assumption changed then this answer will not work.

Comment: Dear @zacdav I am getting `Error: expecting result of length one, got : 10` in the first creation of `num_no`. I am using `dplyr_0.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape to long format, then count the votes, and then take the difference between the Yes values. `data.table::melt` uses regular expression for detecting measure variables, which should be useful in capturing all the `Cause` variables. Does this work?

```
d <-
  melt(as.data.table(DF), # launch melt.data.table
     id.vars = "ID",
     measure.vars = patterns("Cause"), # grep columns
     variable.name = "Cause") %>% 
  group_by(Cause) %>% # tabulate Yes's and No's 
  summarise(Yes = sum(grepl("Yes", value)),
            No = sum(grepl("No", value))) %>%
  mutate(N = lag(Yes) - Yes) %>%  # N = difference between Yes's
  rowwise() %>%  # replace the NA in first row with the No value
  mutate(N = replace(N, is.na(N), No))
```